# Italic style in a label of a list (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, list, flash, label

I have created a list with with lots of labels that work as a menu with scroll. The problem it that I need to italise a part of the label, like a subtitle. So I have this:

```
dp.addItem({ label: 'Hemophilia A Prophylaxis – Background', data: 'dos' });
```

And I need it to be like this:

Hemophilia A Prophylaxis – *Background*

I have seen that there are some thing that you can do in these cases like \n for going to other line but I don't find the way to italise one word.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You would use HTML text and a custom `CellRenderer` to accomplish this:

```
package  
{
    import fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer;

    public class CustomCellRenderer extends CellRenderer
    {
        public function CustomCellRenderer() 
        {
            super();
        }

        override protected function drawLayout():void 
        {
            super.drawLayout();
            textField.htmlText = _label;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would assign your `CustomCellRenderer` to your `List` and use HTML in the label:

```
yourList.setStyle("cellRenderer", CustomCellRenderer);
dp.addItem({ label: 'Hemophilia A Prophylaxis – <i>Background</i>', data: 'dos' });
```